# How to connect and query MySQL DB from python shell job in AWS Glue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, aws-glue

I was using sqlalchemy to create connection and query mySQL DB, however, glue doesn't seem to support "sqlalchemy" or even "pymysql". Is there a way to do this on Glue python shell jobs?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll need to install sqlalchemy and pymysql.  Glue makes it fairly easy to install additional py libs if you're using the Spark runtime, but the py shell runtime seems to be a little different.

The only way I've gotten it to work is to download(or create) whl files.  Luckily, you can download [sqlalchemy](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/c8/1496a0fb6b853eeb2fbd82f0cdd3b5c1ca0a7d46146dc91ce3b65a1616bf/SQLAlchemy-1.4.36-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl) and [pymysql](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4f/52/a115fe175028b058df353c5a3d5290b71514a83f67078a6482cff24d6137/PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl) from pypi. Note: there are many options for the sqlachemy whl file if you need a specific version.

Get those two whl files in a s3 bucket that your glue job will have access to.  Then add both paths (separated by a comma) to the `Python library path` in your Job

example.

`s3://my-bucket/SQLAlchemy-1.4.36-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl,s3://my-bucket/PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl`

Then you should be able to import them like so

```
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql


print('sqlalchemy', sqlalchemy.__version__)
print('pymysql', pymysql.__version__)

May 7, 2022, 9:38:03 AM Pending execution
Processing ./glue-python-libs-ox4yhv_1/SQLAlchemy-1.4.36-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
Collecting greenlet!=0.4.17; python_version >= "3" and (platform_machine == "aarch64" or (platform_machine == "ppc64le" or (platform_machine == "x86_64" or (platform_machine == "amd64" or (platform_machine == "AMD64" or (platform_machine == "win32" or platform_machine == "WIN32"))))))
Downloading greenlet-1.1.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (147 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata; python_version < "3.8"
Downloading importlib_metadata-4.8.3-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting zipp>=0.5
Downloading zipp-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.4; python_version < "3.8"
Downloading typing_extensions-4.1.1-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Installing collected packages: greenlet, zipp, typing-extensions, importlib-metadata, SQLAlchemy
Successfully installed SQLAlchemy-1.4.36 greenlet-1.1.2 importlib-metadata-4.8.3 typing-extensions-4.1.1 zipp-3.6.0
Processing ./glue-python-libs-ox4yhv_1/PyMySQL-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: PyMySQL
Successfully installed PyMySQL-1.0.2
sqlalchemy 1.4.36 pymysql 1.0.2
```